# Update label on post using Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to update a label on an http `post` within a Razor Page. I have a public property called `Confirmation` as follows:

```
public string Confirmation { get; set; }
```

Then I have my `post` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    //some conditional logic here
    Confirmation = "Settings saved!";
    return Page();
}
```

In my view I have:

```
<label asp-for="Confirmation"></label>
```

However, this renders as:

```
<label for="Confirmation">Confirmation</label>
```

1. I don't want the word "Confirmation" showing up in the view, but rather the set value of the property which is "Setting saved!".
2. Also, when the post method executes and I set the string property, it doesn't update the label's text.

I've tried setting the `Confirmation` property in the `OnGetAsync()` method to "" but this still results in the same text displaying on the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `<label asp-for="Confirmation">@Model.Confirmation</label>`.

On a side note, I suspect that you are misusing the label element. It is intended to be paired with a form field of the same name and renders an HTML label. It doesn't help that Win Forms and Web Forms use the `<label>` control as an all-purpose placeholder for outputting text. In Web Forms it renders as a `<span>`, which might be more suitable (although you won't get the tag helper assistance).

Comment: both great answers. there is no need for me to use the asp-for tag in this case as I just want to display the text. the simpler method of using @Model.Confirmation is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The label tag helper works similar to the `Html.LabelFor` html helper, which renders the property name (or display name attribute value of the property). Your property name is "Confirmation", hence you are seeing that in the output when using the label tag helper.

If you want to render the value of the property, you may simply print it using normal razor syntax

```
<label>@Model.Confirmation</label>
```