# ASP Core Razor Pages Change BindProperty Value on Post

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating a form using one razor page (I know this may not be a good idea, but I'm trying to do some [not so] rapid prototyping.  Basically, the first step is that the user enters a bunch of data, and the next step is that the user will upload some files.  My page model looks like this:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DefaultDbContext _context;

    public CreateModel(DefaultDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(Guid id)
    {
        FileUpload = false;
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public bool FileUpload { get; set; } // Stored in a hidden field in my cshtml


    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        FileUpload = true; // Hidden field is always false  
        return Page();
    }
}
```

This is what my form looks like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="FileUpload" />

    @if (!Model.FileUpload)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Upload" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="file" asp-for="Upload" multiple />
            <span asp-validation-for="Upload" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (Model.FileUpload)
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Finished" class="btn btn-primary" />
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click submit the first time, I would expect `FileUpload` to be `true`, which it is when I step through the `.cshtml` page in the debugger.  The problem is that when the page is sent back to the browser, the value is always false:

```
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FileUpload field is required." id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" value="False" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code for the form?

Comment: I have added the code for my form.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034617/12162243), adding `value="@Model.FileUpload"` to the `input` fixes the problem: `<input asp-for="FileUpload" type="hidden" value="@Model.FileUpload"/>` . As to why it doesn't work without it: I'm guessing it just doesn't.

Comment: value="@Model.FileUpload" didn't work.  I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things should be addressed:

1. `<input type="hidden">` elements are useful only when you are trying to send information (contained in those elements) **FROM** the *page* **TO** the *model*, not the vice versa.
2. `[BindProperty]` attribute is used when you are trying to map some information **FROM** the *page* **TO** the *model*'s property, not the vice versa:

   > Model Binding in Razor Pages is the process that takes values **from** HTTP requests and maps them **to** [...] PageModel properties. [Model Binding](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding)
3. In the line `@if (Model.FileUpload)`, you are not extracting any information from the *page*'s hidden `input` element, but from the *model* itself. Your code should work as is (if you ignore the hidden `input` element).

---

That being said, you could completely remove the hidden `input` (and the `[BindProperty]` attribute, since nothing could be bound to `FileUpload` after you remove the `input`) and you should be good to go.

If you do, however, wish to change the hidden `input` value accordingly, you could do that in a couple of ways:

- Remove `[BindProperty]` from the `FileUpload` and keep everything else the same.
- Keep the `[BindProperty]`, but render the changed `FileUpload` value:

  `<input type="hidden" asp-for="FileUpload" value="@Model.FileUpload"/>`